# How to show array element details which includes object details

Tags: json, object

I have to retrieve the data from .json file. While showing the details i am unable to show object details which lies in array

.json

```
{
 "data":{
  "questions":{
           "level":[
              {
                 "question":[
                    {
                       "title":"What does GRC stand for?",
                       "answer":[
                          "Global Technical System",
                          "Global Trade Services",
                          {
                             "_correct":"1",
                             "__text":"Governance, Risk, and Compliance"
                          },
                          "Global Testing Site"
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "title":"Which is not an SAP® version?",
                       "answer":[
                          "4.6C",
                          {
                             "_correct":"1",
                             "__text":"4.7D"
                          },
                          "ECC5",
                          "3.1H"
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "title":"What does BEX stand for?",
                       "answer":[
                          {
                             "_correct":"1",
                             "__text":"Business Explorer"
                          },
                          "Business Executive Exchange",
                          "Business Exhibition"
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "title":"Who is the CEO of SAP®?",
                       "answer":[
                          {
                             "_correct":"1",
                             "__text":"Jim Hagemann Snabe and Bill MCDermott are joint co-CEOs"
                          },
                          "Werner Brandt",
                          "Henning Kagermann",
                          "Hasso Plattner"
                       ]
                    },        
                    {
                       "title":"When was SAP® founded?",
                       "answer":[
                          "1962",
                          {
                             "_correct":"1",
                             "__text":"1972"
                          },
                          "1982"
                       ]
                    }
                 ],
                 "_difficulty":"0",
                 "_title":"SAP® General (Level 1)",
                 "_points_per_question":"10",
                 "_seconds_per_question":"30",
                 "_total_questions":"5"
              }
         }
    }
  }
```

Here i can retrieve the answer array details but i am unable to display _text, _correct details. Could any one suggest the correct way to display the details

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to display _text"? Can you show your code on how you access this attribute?

Comment: Try this `var correct = data.questions.level[0].question[0].answer[2]["_correct"];` //to access _correct attribute of 1 level 1 question

Comment: We should not hard code answer[2] every time. Correct ans may not be always 2.It should display by taking parameter.

Comment: Then you can loop through answer object to get the position of "_correct" like this `var crt = null; $.each(answer, function(i,elem){ if(typeof(elem) == "object"){ crt = elem["_correct"]; } });`